# music for an arcade game?

Tags: assets, sound, audio, music, user-experience

I'm thinking about music for my brick breaker game, but I don't know how to choose any.

If I'd make a loop from a few seconds, I think it would get annoying very quickly. I also found some longer length tracks (about 2 minutes), but when this is over, it's going to be repeated anyway, just like when you'd select a new level, you'd have to listen to the same beginning of the song again.

I can't put an hour of music in my application, so what would you recommend I'd do for the music?

Answer (score 3):

All arcade game music is repetitive **if** you pay attention to it. The music you choose should not be something that is very noticeable. You want your users to be playing your game not listening to the music. The music should just be there to fill in the void of no sounds.

As an example, take a look at the tetris sound tracks.

As a side note, if you are looking for a program to help make sound effects I would suggest trying this: http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html

Answer (score 1):

First, find a loop of music that is a few minutes long, and isn't very annoying to listen to (not too loud, no really obvious parts that'll signal it's repeating), and use that for your game.

Second (and more importantly), give players the ability to *turn off* the music, probably with a single button that is always accessible in the game.

A combination of these should make it possible to have some music that works, but won't get annoying to players, because they can just turn it off when they get bored of it.